# Javascript game help - counting with dice

Tags: javascript

For my assignment, I'm asked to create a game that uses JavaScript. Here is the premise of the game:
At the start of the game, there are ten chips. The player needs to distribute the chips between 11 squares. Each square is designated a number from two to 12. Once player has placed all the chips, he will roll two dice several times. The sum of the dice is recorded and a chip is removed from the corresponding square (if any). The number of rolls needed to remove all 10 chips marks the end of the game.
So I just began the assignment, but I am having trouble keeping a working tally of the number of rolls as it is happening. Parts of it are commented out as I was trying different things. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 div.dice{
     float:left;
     width:32px;
     background:#F5F5F5;
     border:#999 1px solid;
     padding:10px;
     font-size:24px;
     text-align:center;
    margin:5px;
 }
 </style>


 </head>
 <body>
 <script type "text/javascript">
 function rollDice(){
     var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
     var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
     var status = document.getElementById("status");
     var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
     die1.innerHTML = d1;
     die2.innerHTML = d2;
     status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal;
 }

 var count = 0;
 function displayTotal() {
 count = parseInt(count) + parseInt(1);
 var divData = document.getElementById("showCount");
 divData.innerHTML = "Number of Rolls: " + count;
 };


 /**function displayTotal(val) {
 var count = document.getElementById('count').value;
 var new_count = parseInt(count, 10) + val;
 if (new_count < 0) {new_count = 0;}
 document.getElementById('count').value = new_count;
 return new_count;
 } *//
 </script>




 <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
 <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
 <button id = "roll" onclick="rollDice()">Roll Dice</button>
 <div id ="showCount"></div>
 <input type = "button" id = "roll" value = "Roll Dice" onclick = rollDice();/>
 <h2 id="status" style="clear:left;"></h2>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Also, any suggestive information or links I should see to help with making the chips section (that gets subtracted from every time that total comes up on the die) would be extremely helpful. I have no idea how to do that. Also, how do I add one to the chip boxes on click, that's a mystery as well. I guess I could use some suggestions on counts in JS in general.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Didn't want to review all the code for homework, but as an absolutely basic premise... you have initialized a variable "count", but then you do not increment it when your dice roll. Inside of your "displayTotal" you then assign a new value to count.... do not rely on your DOM to store your count, just store it in a variable. You can display the value of the count at any time... from that variable.

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting the two ideas. Should I bring back the commented out section? How exactly do I store it as a variable based on a click? I also don't fully understand how to connect it with the bottom divs. Any hints?

Comment: Sorry, this is probably coming too late. You need to understand that as long as the page isn't reloaded, your JavaScript and any variables you might create are "in memory". They don't need to be connected to any divs at all until their values are required for display. Instead of storing the count in a div and then reading it out again later, you just keep incrementing the count and then displaying it. No reading back in from the DOM.

Comment: @AllenH. I got a working demo of the dice game. Better late than never I guess.

Comment: I didn't make it responsive, so you have to operate it in a full page from the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **UPDATE**

I almost completed this dice game, it does everything the OP requested. I left only one minor thing undone:

- Originally I had planned to dynamically remove the text that represented an array element as the real array element was actually removed. Other than that minor aesthetic flaw, it functions properly and it's UI ain't bad either.
- I just remembered, there is one function I neglected to add was a reset function which is minor as well.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9n56euLmpIv7DKKyaw32?p=preview)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dice</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: 400 16px/1.5'Palatino Linotype';
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #222;
      color: #EFE;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    .shell {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1.5em .75em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .content {
      postion: absolute;
      font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }
    h1 {
      color: hsla(45, 100%, 60%, 1);
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1;
      letter-spacing: .5px;
      font-size: 3rem;
      margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    }
    .die1,
    .die2 {
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, .6);
      border-radius: 7px;
      display: inline-table;
      margin: 2em;
      padding-left: 4px;
    }
    .pip div {
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      background-color: hsla(60, 100%, 80%, 1);
      border-radius: 60px;
      padding: 1px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .row {
      width: 24px;
      height: 8px;
    }
    .blank div {
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      padding: 1px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #tossed,
    #reset {
      height: 32px;
      width: 64px;
      color: hsla(180, 100%, 30%, 1);
      border: 1px inset hsla(228, 100%, 50%, 1);
      border-radius: 7px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-variant: small-caps;
      display: inline-table;
      pointer-events: auto;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #reset {
      display: none;
    }
    #set {
      display: table;
      width: -moz-fit-content;
      width: -webkit-fit-content;
      width: fit-content;
      border: 1px ridge hsla(48, 100%, 50%, 1);
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    #field {
      width: -moz-fit-content;
      width: -webkit-fit-content;
      width: fit-content;
      border: 1px ridge hsla(48, 100%, 50%, 1);
      border-radius: 7px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .subFieldset {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    legend {
      color: hsla(45, 100%, 60%, 1);
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      margin: 0 4em 0 0;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    #set input {
      width: 48px;
      height: 32px;
      background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
      color: hsla(240, 100%, 40%, 1);
      font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px inset hsla(192, 100%, 50%, 1);
      border-radius: 7px;
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
      pointer-events: auto;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    label {
      margin: 0 10px 0 0;
      font-variant: normal;
      display: inline-table;
      color: hsla(60, 100%, 80%, 1);
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    output {
      color: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 1);
      font-family: 'Source Code Pro';
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    #slotDisplay {
      display: table-row;
      float: left;
      clear: both;
      margin: 1em auto;
      background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1);
      border: 1px inset hsla(45, 100%, 60%, 1);
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: hsla(48, 100%, 50%, 1);
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 760px;
      min-width: 320px;
      line-height: 1;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Dice</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="shell">
    <main class="content">
      <section class="box">

        <fieldset id="field">

          <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
          <label for="scored thrown">Score:
            <output id="scored" name="scored" for="ui" form="ui">00</output>
            / Rolls:
            <output id="thrown" name="thrown" for="ui" form="ui">00</output>
          </label>
          <button id="tossed" enabled="false">Roll</button>
        </fieldset>
        <table class="die1">
          <tr class="row">
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row">
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row">
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="die2">
          <tr class="row">
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row">
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row">
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank">
              <div></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </section>
      <form id="ui">
        <fieldset id="set">
          <legend>Distribute Chips in any Combination</legend>
          <label>Chips Remaining:
            <output id="wallet" name="wallet" for="ui" form="ui">10</output>
          </label>
          <br/>
          <section class="subFieldset">
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-2" class="feed" value="02" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-3" class="feed" value="03" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-4" class="feed" value="04" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-5" class="feed" value="05" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-6" class="feed" value="06" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-7 " class="feed" value="07" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-8" class="feed" value="08" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-9" class="feed" value="09" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-10" class="feed" value="10" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-11" class="feed" value="11" form="ui">
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="button" id="b-12" class="feed" value="12" form="ui">
            </label>
          </section>
          <textarea id="slotDisplay" readonly cols="30" rows="1" form="ui"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </main>
  </section>
  <script>
    /*/////////////][ GLOBAL ][//////////////*/
    var slots = [];
    var chip = 10;
    var roll = 0;

    var set = document.getElementById("set");
    /*/////////////][ PHASE I ][//////////////*/
    set.addEventListener("click", execFeed, false);

    function execFeed(event) {
      if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
        var tgt = event.target.id;
        console.log('trueTarget: ' + tgt);
        var feed = document.getElementById(tgt);
        console.log('feed: ' + feed);
        var val = feed.value;
        console.log('val: ' + val);
        var idx = parseInt(splitPop(tgt, '-'), 10) - 2;
        console.log('idx: ' + idx);

        chip = feedSlot(val, slots);
        if (chip === 0) {
          set.removeEventListener('click', execFeed, false);
          tos.setAttribute('enabled', true);
          var str0 = 'Roll the Dice to Match Each Number';
          var col0 = 'lime';
          msg(str0, col0);
        }
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    function feedSlot(val, Arr) {
      var wallet = document.getElementById('wallet');
      var view = document.getElementById('slotDisplay');
      Arr.push(val);
      console.log('Arr: ' + Arr);
      view.value = Arr;
      chip--;
      wallet.value = chip;
      return chip;
    }

    var tos = document.getElementById('tossed');
    /*/////////////][ PHASE II ][//////////////*/
    tos.addEventListener('click', matchRoll, false);

    function execRoll() {
      var thrown = document.getElementById('thrown');
      var scored = document.getElementById('scored');
      var die1 = document.querySelector('.die1');
      var die2 = document.querySelector('.die2');
      var pip1 = selArr('td', die1);
      var pip2 = selArr('td', die2);
      var rd1 = rollDice(pip1);
      var rd2 = rollDice(pip2);
      var points = rd1 + rd2;
      scored.value = leadZero(points, 2);
      roll++;
      thrown.value = leadZero(roll, 2);
      return points;
    }

    function matchRoll() {
      var val = execRoll();
      var tgt = leadZero(val, 2);
      console.log('execRoll: ' + tgt);
      var arr = slots;
      console.log('slots: ' + slots);
      var mR = arr.indexOf(tgt);
      if (mR === -1) {
        var str1 = 'No Match, Roll Again';
        var col1 = 'orange';
        msg(str1, col1);
      } else if (mR > -1 && chip < 9) {
        ++chip;
        var toGo = 10 - chip;
        var str2 = tgt + ' Matched, ' + toGo + ' More Matches Left';
        var col2 = 'blue';
        arr.splice(mR, 1);
        msg(str2, col2);
      } else {
        ++chip;
        var exit = document.getElementById('reset');
        var str3 = 'Completed in ' + roll + ' Rolls';
        var col3 = 'yellow';
        arr.splice(mR, 1);
        msg(str3, col3);
        exit.style.display = "block";
        tos.style.display = "none";
      }
      wallet.value = chip;
      return false;
    }

    function rollDice(arr) {
      var ran6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      blank(arr);
      switch (ran6) {
        case 1:
          arr[4].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[4].classList.add('pip');
          break;
        case 2:
          arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[0].classList.add('pip');
          arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[8].classList.add('pip');
          break;
        case 3:
          arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[0].classList.add('pip');
          arr[4].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[4].classList.add('pip');
          arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[8].classList.add('pip');
          break;
        case 4:
          arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[0].classList.add('pip');
          arr[2].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[2].classList.add('pip');
          arr[6].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[6].classList.add('pip');
          arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[8].classList.add('pip');
          break;
        case 5:
          arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[0].classList.add('pip');
          arr[2].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[2].classList.add('pip');
          arr[4].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[4].classList.add('pip');
          arr[6].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[6].classList.add('pip');
          arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[8].classList.add('pip');
          break;
        case 6:
          arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[0].classList.add('pip');
          arr[2].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[2].classList.add('pip');
          arr[3].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[3].classList.add('pip');
          arr[5].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[5].classList.add('pip');
          arr[6].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[6].classList.add('pip');
          arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
          arr[8].classList.add('pip');
          break;
      }
      var pts = ran6;
      return pts;
    }

    /*/////////////][ UTILITIES ][//////////////*/
    function msg(str, col) {
      var title = document.querySelector('legend');
      title.style.color = col;
      title.innerHTML = str;
    }

    function selArr(sel, ele) {
      if (!ele) {
        ele = document;
      }
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(ele.querySelectorAll(sel));
    }

    function blank(arr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].classList.remove('pip');
        arr[i].classList.add('blank');
      }
      return false;
    }

    function leadZero(num, len) {
      var str = num.toString();
      var zeros = len - str.length;
      for (var i = 1; i <= zeros; i++) {
        str = "0" + str;
      }
      return str;
    }

    function splitPop(str, delim) {
      var strX = str.split(delim).pop();
      return strX;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## **OLD CONTENT**

---

I made the fun part of this dice game, it's up to you, sir to finish the rest. JS is annotated, good luck.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Dice</title>
<style>
html, body { box-sizing: border-box; font: 400 16px/1.5 'Source Code Pro'; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
body { background-color: #222; color: #EFE; font-variant: small-caps;  overflow: hidden; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }
.shell { position: relative; padding: 1.5em .75em; margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
.content { postion: absolute; font-variant: normal; }
.die1, .die2 { width: 48px; height: 48px; background-color: hsla(0,100%,50%,.6); border-radius: 7px; display: inline-table; margin: 2em; padding-left: 4px; }
.pip div { width: 8px; height: 8px; background-color: hsla(60,100%,80%,1); border-radius: 60px; padding: 1px; text-align: center; }
.row { width: 24px; height: 8px; }
.blank div { width: 8px; height: 8px; padding: 1px; text-align: center; }
#toss { height: 32px; width: 64px; border: 1px inset hsla(0,0%,50%,1); border-radius: 6px; text-align: center; font-size: 1.2rem; font-variant: small-caps; display: inline-table; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>Dice</h1>
</header>
<section class="shell">
 <main class="content">
  
 <table class="die1">
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 
 <button id="toss">Roll</button>
 
 <table class="die2">
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row">
 <td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td><td class="blank"><div></div></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
   
 </main>
</section>
<script>
// Reference to Dice (2 tables in DOM)
var die1 = document.querySelector('.die1');
var die2 = document.querySelector('.die2');
// Reference to Pips (2 arrays of table-cells in Dice) derived from selArr(sel, ele)☆  
var pip1 = selArr('td', die1);
var pip2 = selArr('td', die2);
// Reference to the Toss (1 button triggers the random "roll" of the Dice)
var toss = document.getElementById('toss');

/*
** When the Toss button is clicked, execute function roll(arr)★ twice; 
** once for the array of table cells (Pips) in table.die1 (Die One); 
** then the other one in table.die2 (Die Two)
*/
toss.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 roll(pip1);
 roll(pip2);
 return false;
}, false);

/* ★
** Take the array of td (Pips) and add the .blank class to each of them ✪;
** generate a random number 1 thru 6 and determine the layout of the tds (pips)
*/ 
function roll(arr) {
  blank(arr);
  var ran6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  switch(ran6) {
    case 1:
     arr[4].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[4].classList.add('pip');
     break;
    case 2:
     arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[0].classList.add('pip');
     arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[8].classList.add('pip');
     break;
    case 3:
     arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[0].classList.add('pip');
     arr[4].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[4].classList.add('pip');
      arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[8].classList.add('pip');
     break;
     case 4:
     arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[0].classList.add('pip');
     arr[2].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[2].classList.add('pip');
      arr[6].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[6].classList.add('pip');
     arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[8].classList.add('pip');
     break;
    case 5:
     arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[0].classList.add('pip');
     arr[2].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[2].classList.add('pip');
     arr[4].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[4].classList.add('pip');
      arr[6].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[6].classList.add('pip');
     arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[8].classList.add('pip');
     break;
    case 6:     
     arr[0].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[0].classList.add('pip');
     arr[2].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[2].classList.add('pip');
     arr[3].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[3].classList.add('pip');
      arr[5].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[5].classList.add('pip');
     arr[6].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[6].classList.add('pip');
     arr[8].classList.remove('blank');
     arr[8].classList.add('pip');
     break;
  }
}
/* ☆
** selArr(sel, ele) (selectorArray) this utility takes a collection of selectors
** and converts them into a real array
*/ 
function selArr(sel, ele) {
 if(!ele) {
  ele = document;
 }
 return Array.prototype.slice.call(ele.querySelectorAll(sel));
} 
/* ✪
** blank(arr) takes an array of td (Pips) and  adds the .blank class to each one of them
*/
function blank(arr) {
 for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].classList.remove('pip');
  arr[i].classList.add('blank'); 
 }
 return false;
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice dice :) It was certainly an interesting approach to creating them. While I am not sure this solves the issue the OP was facing, I like it. +1

Comment: @TravisJ  I know  I reread the question and I'm almost done with the a solution, and thank you , sir  :-)

Comment: Those are indeed great looking dice. I'm not quite having issues with making the dice, things work great if I take the counter part out of it. Any suggestions for what I can do to solve that problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @AllenH. I'm having troubles with the counter part too, I'd post what I have so far but I don't want SOTrolls downvoting me.